# DCF Zero Coupon Bond

Tags: fixed-income

Using a 30/360 day count what is the exact formula to discount this single zero coupon bond?

```
DayCount:   30/360
Start Date  6/25/2013
End Date    1/1/2020
Discount Rate   3.50%

Present Value   
Ending Value    50,000,000
```

Comment: Like we ask all other homework questions: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Well the formula I am using is =50,000/(1+.035)^(something). The problem is I don't know what power to raise it too. Zero coupon bonds have n=1 frequency. Do I raise it to the ^(Diff.Date(6/25/2013,1/1/2020)/360) ?

Answer (score 1):

- DF(t1) = 1/((1+r/360)^360*T)
- Using 30/360 Daycount convention, you get 2346 days to discount over.
- Your discount factor should work out to about 0.7961 and hence your PV of the cash flow should be about 39,803,337.23.

Comment: Matt, I just don't understand where you are getting the r/360 and the 360*T. Shouldn't we be dividing the discount rate "r" by the frequency of the cashflows, which in this case is 1? Not to mention, 360*T=360*(#of days/360)=# of days. 

Why are you raising to the number of days? Not the number of years?s

Comment: It has to do with what compounding frequency you apply. If you compound annually then the 360 term would drop out. Please see my edited answer here: http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/8497/30360-daycount-count-convention-to-find-npv-for-bonds/8498?noredirect=1#comment13227_8498

Comment: @jessica, does that answer your question?